# Why does my JavaScript instances return the same?

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm trying to make two instances (`constructorOne` and `constructorTwo`) of a function variable called `myObjectConstructor`. For some reason I get the same result back for both instances when I call `getProperty`.

```
//this is one other way of creating a Constructor function
var myObjectConstructor = function(){
    this.myProperty = '';

    init = function(str) {
       this.myProperty = str;
    },

    getProperty = function() {
       return this.myProperty;
    }     

    return {
        init: function () {
            return init.apply(self, arguments);
        },
        getProperty: function () {
            return getProperty.apply(self, arguments);
        }
    }
}

//instantiate our Constructor
var constructorOne = new myObjectConstructor();

//change myProperty of the first instance
constructorOne.init('this is property one');

//instantiate a second instance of our Constructor
var constructorTwo = new myObjectConstructor();

constructorTwo.init('this is property two');
```

Both `constructorOne.getProperty()` and `constructorTwo.getProperty()` will alert "*this is property two*":

```
alert(constructorOne.getProperty()); //this will alert 'this is property two'
alert(constructorTwo.getProperty()); //this will still alert 'this is property two'
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/espwx77k/).

Question is, why does `constructorOne.getProperty()` not return 'this is property one'?

Comment: Because you are referencing `this` in both objects which has been overwritten in the moment the second object has been initialised.

Comment: Because `self` is not defined, and therefore `getProperty` is called in the context of `window` both times.

Comment: how to use constructor functions and prototype is explained here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941 hope it helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`self` is `undefined` so inside the init function, `this` is `window`, so you are always modifying properties of the same object.

You seem to be doing some weird hybrid of the module pattern and standard JavaScript constructor functions. I strongly suggest picking one of the two approaches and sticking to it.

```js
function MyObjectConstructor(){
    this.myProperty = '';
}

MyObjectConstructor.prototype.init = function(str) {
       this.myProperty = str;
};
MyObjectConstructor.prototype.getProperty = function() {
       return this.myProperty;
};
 
//instantiate our Constructor
var constructorOne = new MyObjectConstructor();
 
//change myProperty of the first instance
constructorOne.init('this is property one');
 
//instantiate a second instance of our Constructor
var constructorTwo = new MyObjectConstructor();
 
constructorTwo.init('this is property two');

//alert current myProperty of constructorOne instance
alert(constructorOne.getProperty()); 

 //alert current myProperty of constructorTwo instance
alert(constructorTwo.getProperty());
```

or

```js
function myModule (){
  var myProperty = '';
  return {
    init: function (str) {
       myProperty = str;
    },
    getProperty: function () {
      return myProperty;
    }
  };  
}

//instantiate our Constructor
var constructorOne = myModule();
 
//change myProperty of the first instance
constructorOne.init('this is property one');
 
//instantiate a second instance of our Constructor
var constructorTwo = myModule();
 
constructorTwo.init('this is property two');

//alert current myProperty of constructorOne instance
alert(constructorOne.getProperty()); 

 //alert current myProperty of constructorTwo instance
alert(constructorTwo.getProperty());
```

Comment: If I use your first option (with prototype), and have functions in my object that need to call each other, how would I do this?

Let's say I have these two functions:

MyObjectConstructor.prototype.func1 = function(str) {
}

MyObjectConstructor.prototype.func2 = function(str) {
   how to call func1 from here?
}

Comment: You continue to get a reference to the object with `this`: `this.func1()`

Answer (score 1):

A better way of doing this would be using proper prototypes:

```
function MyObjectConstructor() {
    this.property = '';
}

MyObjectConstructor.prototype.init = function(newProperty) {
    this.property = newProperty;
};

MyObjectConstructor.prototype.getProperty = function() {
    return this.property;
};
```